# C# - Obtain substrings as list from the given string in the given below format

Tags: c#

```
  MemberOf: [12]IdentityDescriptor instance 4r34984
  Identifier: S-1-9-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-0-0-0-0-1
  IdentityType: Identity1
, IdentityDescriptor instance 4854
  Identifier: S-1-xx-xxx-xxxx
  IdentityType: Identity2
, IdentityDescriptor instance 2437y28
  Identifier: S-1-5-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-5684648
  IdentityType: Identity3
```

the above entire is one string
Now i need to  obtain the substring as 
List consisting of the following

```
S-1-9-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-0-0-0-0-1
S-1-xx-xxx-xxxx
S-1-5-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-168324
```

and another List as following

```
Identity1
Identity2
Identity3
```

Comment: you could use RegularExpressions and Captures to get Groups , a collection of the values you want.

Comment: Try writing the code yourself. If you have a problem, then ask a real question. Why should anyone do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex` to find them.

`(?<=IdentityType: ).*$` will capture the relevant information on those lines, and

`(?<=Identifier: ).*$` will capture that line.

[See it in action here](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/17)